# How to completely hide groupview in BaseExpandableListAdapter when there are no children?

Tags: android

I am using BaseExpandableListAdapter to display an ExpandableList, and i want to hide groups when getChildrenCount returns 0. I tried to setVisibility(View.GONE) to convertView in getGroupView method, but group rectangle is still in the list and it is empty- and it is not what i wanted, i want not to see it there. Any ideas how to hide it?

Comment: remove it from your adapter

Comment: I think, i will just remove it from header array, before adapter processes it